# My PhpStorm IDE is not recognizing certain code such as this.$store

Tags: vue.js, ide, phpstorm, nuxt.js, webstorm

My PhpStorm IDE is giving unresolved variable errors etc for code that is completely fine.

This is happening on stuff such as `this.$v`, `this.$store`, `this.$auth` etc.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? (it will still run perfectly fine, I just find it annoying and harder for debugging)

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: what IDE version is it? Also, do you have the `d.ts` files for the corresponding libraries installed (`npm install  @types/vuelidate` for `$v`, etc.)?

Comment: PhpStorm 2020.1, I just did types vuelidate and that worked for $v, do you know what I'd need to install for this.$store?